# Getting WELD-001303 error when implementing custom CDI extension for @SessionScoped scope

Tags: cdi, java-ee-7, named-scope, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to implement a **custom CDI scope** and I thought it's the easiest to start by extending the existing `@SessionScoped`. I started by following [this tutorial](http://niklasschlimm.blogspot.ch/2011/07/custom-scopes-in-cdi-10-and-spring-31.html). However, when visiting an XHTML page which references a CDI bean with my scope, this leads to

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type myscope.MyScoped
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:687)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:740)
at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:170)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:272)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(UIViewAction.java:562)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
... 31 more
```

My annotation is

```
@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@NormalScope
public @interface MyScoped {
}
```

My context is

```
public class MyScopeContext extends HttpRequestContextImpl {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> getScope() {
        return MyScoped.class;
    }
}
```

(note that I inherit from `org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl`.)

And my Extension is

```
public class MyScopeExtension implements Extension {
    public void afterBeanDiscovery(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery event, BeanManager manager) {
        event.addContext(new MyScopeContext());
    }
}
```

---

I'm running on GlassFish 4.1 with `javax:javaee-web-api:7.0` and `org.jboss.weld:weld-core:1.1.29.Final` on the classpath.

I'm almost sure I made some basic error, but what is it?

Comment: At any point in your code are you activating/deactivating the context? It looks like you're just throwing it away the way you have it defined.

Comment: @JohnAment, could you elaborate more on how to do this? I didn't manage to find documentation on how to activate a custom scope. I'm ready to accept this as an answer if it solves my problem.

Comment: You didn't find it in the docs because you're extending from weld's internally classes - not recommended.  Here's bound context for your review.  https://docs.jboss.org/weld/javadoc/2.0/weld-api/org/jboss/weld/context/BoundContext.html  I'll put together a more complete answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found out what I did wrong.

I wasn't aware that I have to register my CDI Extension by creating the file src/main/resources/META-INF/services/**javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension** with this content:

```
myscope.MyScopeExtension
```

I also found a sample implementation of a CDI custom scope on GitHub: https://github.com/rmpestano/cdi-custom-scope

I still didn't quite manage to finish my implementation, thus I will continue my research...